# Я новичок в python и не могу найти ошибку в коде

Tags: python

```
def корабля (бляшанки):
    всього_бляшанок= 0 
    for тиждень in range(1, 53):
        всього_бляшанок = всього_бляшанок + бляшанки
        print('Тиждень %s = %s бляшанок' % (тиждень, \ всього_бляшанок))
```

Ошибка:

> SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character

[image]

Comment: для начала замени все элементы программы на латиницу.

Answer (score 2):

Уберите символ слэша в print'е после тиждень, .
должно быть так:

```
print('Тиждень %s = %s бляшанок' % (тиждень, всього_бляшанок))
```

Answer (score 1):

1.Возможно программа не понимает чему равен тиждень. Он не обозначен в функции

```
def корабля (бляшанки): #тут вы передаете бляшанки в функцию
#вы не передали в функцию чему равен тиждень.
    for тиждень in range(1, 53): #у вас получается NULL in range(1, 53)
```

2. Еще у вас странная запятая в последней строке `тиждень,` либо `\`
3. print в конце я бы сделала так:

   ```
    tigden = 151515
    vsego_blyashanok = 150105 / 5
    print('Tigden ' + str(tigden) + "=" + str(vsego_blyashanok))
   ```